# Xcode Undefined Symbols For Architecture will not run in 64-bit simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I am getting an `Undefined Symbols For Architecture i386` only when I try to run in the `iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)` simulator. Project runs fine in the `iPhone Retina (4-inch)` simulator and `iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)` simulator.

I changed the Architectures in my Build Settings to armv7 and armv7s (both Architectures and Valid Architectures) but still will not work in 64-bit simulators.

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and Cocos2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so since I was using Cocos2D, there are two Targets ... one for my project, and a second Target that is called `cocos2d libraries`.

I had only changed the Architectures on my project Target, but not on the `cocos2d libraries` Target.

Once I changed the Architectures on this second Target as well to `armv7` and `armv7s` then it worked properly and will now run in the 64-bit simulators as well.